# Python Ctypes Define Out Int Array to Function

Tags: python, c, dll, integer, ctypes

I have CDLL library, i try to call library functions from Python but im stuck.

```
C
int GetData(int specIndex, int Data[]);

Python 
DLL.GetData(index,Data)
```

Which ctypes i need to choose on Data.
I try to define int array ( (c_int*size)() ) but i dont know size of data.

Comment: Hint: `int GetData(int specIndex, int Data[]);` and `int GetData(int specIndex, int *Data);` are equivalent.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  One-liners with no context we can't fix.